# iOS UIImage imageOrientation inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I'm having an issue in an iOS share extension when users share a photo from the Photos app or from the camera.

I'm using the `imageRotation` property to rotate the image once it's loaded into my application.

```
switch (img.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        rotation = @"90";
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        rotation = @"0";
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        rotation = @"180";
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        rotation = @"270";
        break;
}
```

On most devices, this works fine. However, on my personal device (iPhone Xr with 13.4.1), the `UIImage` is already rotated appropriately and using the rotation value from the switch statement over-rotates (so `UIImageOrientationDown` will actually display upside down after being rotated by 180 degress). If I don't rotate the image on my device, the images are all oriented correctly, but on others the rotation does need to happen. I'm not able to find anything in the `UIImage` I can key off of to prevent the rotation.

Has anyone else ever run into this situation? Is it a setting on my device? Is there something I can use to determine if I should rotate the image or not?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the example code here is missing the 'mirrored' enum options but they also aren't coming up.  On the problematic device I'm getting the appropriate rotation based on how the camera was held while taking the picture, but performing the rotation is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

It's because you still not implemented all the case.
For more information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/orientation

It's the same with orientation of the device.